# Will excel file generation process run on webserver risk file locks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop

I am wondering if I need to do something(threading etc.) to preclude my file generation failing due to more than one user attempting to run the generation process simultaneously.

If there is a potential problem I want to know any ideas for avoiding it.

Overview of my process.

1. user clicks button to kick off the process.
2. Data is collected from datasource/dummied up for testing.
3. Template.xls is opened
4. data is inserted into opened template.
5. SaveAs is called for the open excel file.
6. process is repeated until all needed files are created.
7. All files zipped together
8. user is informed if process completed successfully and prompted to download the zip of the files.

note: hardcoded filename values are present due to this being a proof of concept at the moment.

See generation code below

```
private Boolean GenerateExcelFile(int filenum, int totalfiles, int Year)
    {
        String TemplateFilename = "C:\\exceldocs\\Templates\\OSHA300_Template.xls";

        try
        {
            Excel._Application oXL;
            Excel._Workbook oWB;
            Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

            //Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = false;

            //Open the workbook template.
            //oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
            oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(TemplateFilename));
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

            oSheet.Cells[3, 11] = Year;
            oSheet.Cells[PAGEOFROW, PAGEOFCOL] = filenum + " of " + totalfiles;
            int currentexcelrow = STARTROW;
            foreach (OSHArow row in this)
            {
                FillOutRow(oSheet, row, currentexcelrow++);
                if (currentexcelrow == 38)
                {
                    //break;
                }
            }
            FillOutSummaryRow(oSheet);
            File.Delete("C:\\exceldocs\\OshaOutput\\OSHA300_TestResult" + filenum + ".xls");
            oWB.SaveAs("C:\\exceldocs\\OshaOutput\\OSHA300_TestResult" + filenum + ".xls");
            oWB.Close(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO: configure an exception log.
            throw e;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use Office Interop in a server application, for many reasons. Also, never do `throw e`. Use `throw;` instead. In your case, get rid of the try/catch entirely.

Comment: this would be more appropriate on codereview.SE

Comment: @Dan-o: disagree. The fact you can't Office Interop in ASP.NET or another server application is definitely [SO].

Comment: @JohnSaunders: ok.  Also, "can't Office interop in ASP.NET" is a new one on me.  I know its a *VERY BAD* idea, but if Office is installed on the web server the interop should "work" - as well as office interop "works", no?

Comment: @Dan-o: no, it shouldn't "work", and usually doesn't "work" - if you're lucky. If you're not lucky, it will appear to work, until you depend on it. It will then break in ways difficult to "fix", and it _still_ won't actually work.

Comment: @Dan-o: all that code was written to automate desktop applications (Office) from other desktop applications (your extensions). The server environment is very different. For instance: only a single user vs. all the users on your web site;

Comment: @Jeremy: you won't be able to "fail gracefully". You'll have no idea how the code that failed has screwed up your application. This code wasn't meant to be run by several users at the same time.

Comment: @Dan-o: I don't have time to find it right now, but type [office-interop][asp.net] into the search box and see what you find.

Comment: 1) I have been convinced to find a different method to generate the file.
2) Simply letting the exception happen means that the user sees a screen that says an exception happened while not even displaying what it is because remote error display is routinely disabled. So I might be told something went wrong, but I get no real diagnostic information.

What should I do rather than note the error, log it and notify a developer(me), then take the user to an error screen that isn't the default asp broke screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using something like the OpenXml library. You can write Excel sheets on the fly to streams (and then return streams as FileResults for the user to download to a XLSX file).

http://openxmldeveloper.org/

Comment: How difficult is it to open a template file shove data into it and keep the formatting. I tried using Excel Library but it kept eating the formatting which is unacceptable.

Comment: It is possible to specify formatting in Open XML; it can be a little cumbersome. I don't recall if there are options for starting a new document from a template or not but I would assume that they exist.